# AngularJS: directives firing out of order

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives, let's call them `A` and `B`. `A` is on an ancestor of `B`:

```
<div data-a>
  <div data-b></div>
</div>
```

The postLink function of directive `B` is firing before `A`'s.

I've tried playing with their priorities, making `B` require `A`, but still no change.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding execution order of directives?

Comment: See this response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18491502/2338813 - it explains that post link functions fire in inner-to-outer order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling order of link function in nested and repeated angularjs directives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294726/calling-order-of-link-function-in-nested-and-repeated-angularjs-directives)