# Angular ng-repeat ng-isolate-scope in each child

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to tell `ng-repeat` that a directive inside is an isolated scope, but not each child?

```
<div class="item" ng-class="{active: $index === 0}" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <image-zoom img-src="{{image.catalog}}"></image-zoom>
</div>
```

And:

```
app.directive('imageZoom', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            imageSrc: "@"
        },
        template: '<zoom class="container-fluid" zoom-imagesrc="{{imageSrc}}">' +
            '<zoom-image-container class="zoom-image-container"></zoom-image-container>' +
            '<aside>' +
            '<zoom-control class="zoom-control"></zoom-control>' +
            '</aside>' +
            '</zoom>'
    }
});
```

Produces (note `ng-isolate-scope` for each child):

```
<!-- ngRepeat: image in images -->
<div class="item ng-scope active" ng-class="{active: $index === 0}" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <image-zoom img-src="img/items/red-5.jpg" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <zoom class="container-fluid ng-isolate-scope" zoom-imagesrc="">
            <zoom-image-container class="zoom-image-container ng-isolate-scope">
                <div class="zoom-image-container__clip">
                    <img ng-src="">
                </div>
            </zoom-image-container>
            <aside>
                <zoom-control class="zoom-control ng-isolate-scope">
                    <div class="zoom-control__clip">
                        <img ng-src="">
                        <div class="mark"></div>
                    </div>
                </zoom-control>
            </aside>
        </zoom>
    </image-zoom>
</div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: image in images -->
```

Is there a way to get this?:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: image in images -->
<div class="item ng-scope active" ng-class="{active: $index === 0}" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <image-zoom img-src="img/items/red-5.jpg" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <zoom class="container-fluid" zoom-imagesrc="">
            <zoom-image-container class="zoom-image-container">
                <div class="zoom-image-container__clip">
                    <img ng-src="">
                </div>
            </zoom-image-container>
            <aside>
                <zoom-control class="zoom-control">
                    <div class="zoom-control__clip">
                        <img ng-src="">
                        <div class="mark"></div>
                    </div>
                </zoom-control>
            </aside>
        </zoom>
    </image-zoom>
</div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: image in images -->
```

The end problem is that `zoom-image-container` and `zoom-control`  needs to communicate to `zoom` (directive+controller) with a controller. When they acces to the controller, the properties that have been assigned to scope in the link function of `zoom` directive, have been are removed.

**EDIT**

Finally I've found that the problem is that the link functions for `zoom-image-container` and `zoom-control` where called before than the link function for `zoom` so I've solved with broadcasting.

Anyway I would be really interested in knowing why they are called before than parent directive link function (maybe this is because of `require: '^zoom'`?).

Comment: any usefull ? http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/

Comment: Thanks, but not really, I've improved the question

Comment: Are `zoom-image-container` and `zoom-control` not defined with scope:{} ? Also, are you already using `require: '^zoom'` to inject the zoom controller into the child directives and have them communicate ?

Comment: Yes, I've found that the problem is that the link functions for `zoom-image-container` and `zoom-control` where called first than the link function for `zoom` so I've solved with broadcasting. Anyway I would be interested in knowing why they are called first than parent link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those links should be of help to understand the order of execution of link functions :

[Calling order of link function in nested and repeated angularjs directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294726/calling-order-of-link-function-in-nested-and-repeated-angularjs-directives)

http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives/

Basically, `link` by default is a postlink, which is called last. It should be safe to manipulate the dom by then, so children directives' postlink has already been executed by the time the parent's postlink is executed !

Comment: Great answer, thanks, this is why I had to use broadcast events from parent to child, to ensure the properties where set. Do you know any other 'elegant/efficient' way to achieve it?